# Is there a sliding plug-in for Compiz-Fusion?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiz

I'm looking for a Compiz-Fusion plug-in that slides windows in on open and out on close, preferably from and to the bottom edge of the screen. The plug-ins that ship don't appear to provide this effect and haven't been able to find one on the net. Does anyone know if one exists?

**Update: Setting up the plugin**

1. Enable Animations Add-On effects plugin in the Compiz Settings Manager
2. Find the Skewer animation and set the following:

   - Skewer Direction: `Down`
   - Tessellation Type: `Rectangle`
   - Window Grid Width: `1`
   - Window Grid Height: `1`
   - Thickness of Animated Polygons: `0`
   - Rotation Angle: `0`
3. In the Animations plugin I added the following for the Open Effect:

   - Open Effect: `Skewer`
   - Duration: `100`
   - Window Match: `((type=Normal | Unknown) | name=sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer | name=sun-awt-X11-XDialogPeer) & !(role=toolTipTip | role=qtooltip_label) & !(type=Normal & override_redirect=1) & !(name=gnome-screensaver)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Animations Add-On plugin, there's an animation called Skewer. It causes pieces of the window to slide in. You can try setting that plugin to only slide in from below, and setting it to only have one piece. That should give you what you want.

Comment: Ding! We have a winner! After I enabled Animations Add-On I saw the Skewer animation. See my question for how I set it up.